# Scala - Pad an array to a certain size

Tags: scala

I have a method:

```
def loadRom(filename: String) : Array[Int] = {
  val is = new FileInputStream(filename)
  Stream.continually(is.read).takeWhile(-1 !=).toArray
}
```

It returns an array of `0x8000` (I can always guarantee that). I want to load it into an array of `0x200000` size. Is there an elegant way to do that? What about padding it out to `0x200000`?

**Edit: Whoops. I JUST noticed the padTo method does what I want. Close?**

Comment: You can answer your own questions and mark it as correct.

Comment: I did that a few years ago and was flamed. Haven't since.

Comment: Well then, things have changed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Answer (score 8):

For completeness's sake, there's `SeqLike.padTo` (arrays implicitly extend `SeqLike`). Assuming you want to pad with zero bytes, just append `.padTo(0x200000, 0)` to the result expression and you're good to go.