# Scala - List take - OrElse - with default value

Tags: scala, list, collections, take

I am trying to implement a way to take `n` from a Scala List, but i`f n > list.length`, specify a default value. Something like takeOrElse.

Say, `val l = List(4, 6, 10)`

```
val taken = l.takeOrElse(5, 0) //List(4, 5, 6, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way to do this idiomatically without mutation and buffers? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `take` and `padTo` functions on `List`.

The `take` returns a new `List` with the n first elements of the list, or the whole list if n was less than the length of the list.

The `padTo` function will add elements to the `List` until its length is equal to the value in its first parameter. It will do nothing if the list is already long enough.

Like this:

```
val taken = l.take(5).padTo(5, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.padTo`,

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.take(5).padTo(len = 5, elem = 0)
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

similar question: [Scala - Pad an array to a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13473029/432903)

**You can also write extension method `takeOrElse` on `List[Int]`,**

```
scala>     implicit class ListOps(list: List[Int]) {
     |       def takeOrElse(length: Int, elem: Int): List[Int] = {
     |         list.take(length).padTo(len = length, elem = elem)
     |       }
     |     }
defined class ListOps

scala> val newList = l.takeOrElse(5, 0)
newList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 0, 0)
```

Also see: [Scala extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297857/432903)